# Replace the faces of an ico sphere with a 3d model

Tags: modeling, workflow

**Hello Everyone!**

For reference, I am using blender 2.79. However, given that this task is relatively simple, it's okay if you're solution is given in blender 2.8 or any other blender version.

That out of the way, **here is the problem I am trying to solve:**

I am attempting to build a tool to allow someone to draw vectors in physical space. In practice, this means I'm trying to get a series of different arrows to attach via 3d printed Velcro to a 3d printed ball. I have found the following 3d printable Velcro: https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:12798.

My goal is to replace the faces of an ico sphere with this Velcro plane, thus fulfilling my purpose of having the velcro ball. I have to do so without distorting Velcro as it may not work anymore, given that distortion.

How can I go about doing this?

Comment: Have a look at the tissue addon.

Comment: Tissue is giving me results close to what I need, but they're still off. When I tessellate to the ico sphere using an edited version of the Velcro that sits on a flat plane I get the result on the top right of this image: https://i.imgur.com/conLQjd.png